# How do I run a python 2.7 code from my Java?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, cmd

I have a Java Swing class from which I want my Java application to run a local python program after clicking a button. The following code does not run the executable python I have created.

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Process process = 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\hello.exe");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have even tried running the python script file using:

```
     private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {

        Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Python27\\python.exe \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\hello.py\"");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have no errors yet neither does the job. I can run applications like notepad etc using the same syntax, however I cant with python and I'm unsure how to resolve this. 
P.s. I do have Python 2.7 PATH in my environment variable. Also, the above are just the methods for the action performed by the buttons. I have all the other methods and main class in my full program.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c /K \"C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\hello.py\"");
```

do this way.. call the Python from cmd

---

I tried this simple example & it worked for me...
Files : `CallPython.java` & `hello.py`

**CallPython.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class CallPython{

    public static void main(String args[]){

       try{
            Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python hello.py");
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            /*
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            */

            stdInput.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Error occured while executing an external process...");
        }
    }
}
```

**hello.py**

```
print('Hello...from python script');
```

Output:

```
 Hello...from python script
```

[image: Snippet of output]

Comment: I tried..it's still not working. Nothing happens when I'm pressing my button.

Comment: I see.. it might be problem with the button click event, can you try printing something instead of running a python script. (Just to make sure the action works!!)

Comment: If I replace the command with: Process p = runTime.exec("notepad.exe");  notepad opens when I click the button so the button is working, only having this problem with python

Comment: what do you get when you run "python path/to/yourScript.py" through the code? as python environment variable set..

Comment: I modified my answer with a simple example I tried and that works fine..